# Multiple inputs with same name and different name

Tags: php, html, forms, foreach

How to receive 2 multiple inputs form in php file

this is the code of php and html

```
<?php 
    $select_being = @mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `being_asked`');
    $show_qu = '';
    while($select_being_result = @mysql_fetch_array($select_being))
    {
        $ask_id = $select_being_result['id'];
        $ask_que = $select_being_result['question'];
        $show_qu .= ' <tr>
        <td>'.$ask_que.'</td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="home['.$ask_id.']" value="1" />Yes</td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="home['.$ask_id.']" value="0" />No
        <input type="hidden" name="hid['.$ask_id.']" value="'.$ask_id.'" />

        </td>
        </tr>'; 

        }
?>
        <form id="Decision" action="sub_being.php?id=<?php echo $manuscript_id ?>" method="post">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr class="trd">
        <td>Question</td>
        <td colspan="2">Answer</td>
         </tr>
        <?php echo $show_qu  ?>
        <tr>
       <td colspan="5"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
       </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
```

I was try this code ro receive but it give me error

```
$answer = $_POST['home'];
$id = $_POST['hid'];
foreach($answer as $value) {
$insert = @mysql_query('INSERT INTO `being_asked_report`(`re_id`,`manu_id`,`answer`,`que_id`)VALUE('.$reviewer_id.','.$manuscript_id.','.$value.')');
if($insert)
{
    echo 'done <br />';
    foreach($id as $que_id)
    {

    }
}

}
```

I Know that this question is repeated but i can't understand any resolve form my case

Comment: What error does it give you?

Comment: whats the value of `home['.$ask_id.']` and `hid['.$ask_id.']` ?? you have to use that value in your `action` page... in `$_POST['your_value']`... you are using `$_POST['home']`.. which is wrong..

Comment: home['.$ask_id.'] to multiple inputs which is cheked

Answer (score 0):

First of all: please avoid using those @-signs with your mysql_* functions. When something is not working in the future you're hiding the errors. Should keep you from ending up frustrated.

Second, you're on the right track. I guess changing

```
foreach($answer as $value) {
```

to

```
foreach($answer as $key => $value) {
```

will help you getting the right value.
The ID of your question will then be the $key. If this is not working, try print_r on your $_POST (with  tags) to make it understandable for yourself.

Comment: I have to multiple values want to insert to row
First $ask_id
Second $que_id

Comment: Add a fourth value to your query, because 4 columns and 3 values won't work (you would know without the @). I guess I don't understand you correctly, because in my opinion you can leave out the hidden input and just use $key in my second piece of code for the que_id field in your query.

Comment: I can't use $key because, I have different question ID not key 1,2,3

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Let me know if this works for you.

```
<?php 
$select_being = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `being_asked`');
?>

<form id="Decision" action="sub_being.php?id=<?php echo $manuscript_id; ?>" method="post">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr class="trd">
            <td>Question</td>
            <td colspan="2">Answer</td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        while($select_being_result = mysql_fetch_assoc($select_being))
        {
            $ask_id = $select_being_result['id'];
            $ask_que = $select_being_result['question'];
            echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>'.$ask_que.'</td>';
                echo '<td><input type="radio" name="home['.$ask_id.']" value="1" />Yes</td>';
                echo '<td><input type="radio" name="home['.$ask_id.']" value="0" />No';
                echo '<input type="hidden" name="hid['.$ask_id.']" value="'.$ask_id.'" />';
                echo '</td>';
            echo '</tr>'; 
        }
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Second block which im assuming is `sub_being.php`

```
<?php
$manu_id = $_GET['id'];
$answers = $_POST['home'];
$id = $_POST['hid'];
foreach($answers as $key => $value) 
{
    $query = 'INSERT INTO `being_asked_report` (`re_id`,`manu_id`,`answer`,`que_id`) VALUES ('.$reviewer_id.','. $manu_id .','.$value.','.$key.')';
    $insert = mysql_query($query);
    if($insert)
    {
        echo $query . ' succesful.</br>'
    }else
    {
        echo mysql_errno() . '</br>';
    }
} 
?>
```

Comment: Also it has been said over and over on nearly any question making use of mysql_*. Use mysqli or PDO to handle queries and learn it the right way from the start don't bother with mysql_* functions as they will not be supported in future versions of PHP and will conflict with newer environments in which your program or site might be running. Even if it's for learning purposes use mysqli_* or PDO.

Comment: I can't use $key because, I have different question ID not key 1,2,3